# Jenkins/Kubernetes cannot clone from gitea repository with valid cert

Tags: ssl, jenkins, kubernetes, gitea

I am using Jenkins with Kubernetes agents, trying to build a Gitea-hosted git repository using an organizational folder configuration. When my build triggers, I get

```
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://<servername.com>/homelab/java-spring-microservice.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none
```

The repository (also hosted within the kubernetes cluster) has a valid LetsEncrypt certificate on its ingress (managed by cert-manager.) I'm able to clone this repo fine from git command-line (without having TLS disabled.)

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
podTemplate(containers: [
  containerTemplate(
    name: 'maven',
    image: 'maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11',
    command: 'sleep',
    args: '30d'
  )
]) {
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout scm
      container('maven') {
        stage('Build') {
          sh '''
            mvn clean package
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked around and seen ways to get around this by disabling TLS for the git operation, but that seems wrong-headed to me, since TLS appears to be working. I'll admit to being a bit uncertain of how exactly all this works when things are under kubernetes (where should I be looking to see if the CA trust chain is correct, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I determined that both the version of jenkins/inbound-agent and the version of jenkins itself were built against base images that did not have up-to-date CA trust chains. I was able to resolve the problem by updating to the latest Jenkins, updating the pod template for kubernetes, and updating the kubernetes plugin for jenkins.